# Compressing/decompressing char array using zlib, some characters missing

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I've written a program, which, supposedly, should compress and then uncompress the string using zlib functions compress() and uncompress(), it compiles just fine, but for some reason, when I start it, some symbols from the uncompressed string are missing - what I get is "some " and then some system symbols. Could anyone help me in finding the mistake here?

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "zlib.h"
int main()
{
const char *istream = "some foo";
ulong destLen = strlen(istream);
char* ostream = malloc(2 * strlen(istream));
int res = compress(ostream, &destLen, istream, destLen + 1);


const char *i2stream = ostream;
char* o2stream = malloc(4 * strlen(istream));
ulong destLen2 = strlen(i2stream);
int des = uncompress(o2stream, &destLen2, i2stream, destLen2);
printf("%s", o2stream);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of strlen() in this code.

Comment: It's way far from being optimised, and this is just a prototype, I intend to split this into 2 functions, but it is isn't working as intended, and I have no idea why

Comment: How do you know that compressed data fits into `ostream` of size `2*strlen(istream)` for such a short input? Did you check return of compress for `Z_MEM_ERROR` or `Z_MEM_ERROR` ?

Comment: @luk32 oh, indeed, that was dumb of me not to check for the error codes. How much memory would you suggest for me to allocate for the output buffer for compress?

Comment: `compressBound()`. Take a look at the answer, I think I got everything right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Check the error codes!!**

```
luk32:gcc -lz ./zlib.c 
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ./a.out 
Buffer was too small!
```

Compression is often ineffective for very small inputs. Therefore your prediction for the needed buffer size  being `2*strlen(istream)` was an underestimation.

"Improved" `zlib.c` to check what went wrong:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "zlib.h"
int main()
{
  const char *istream = "some foo";
  ulong destLen = strlen(istream);
  char* ostream = malloc(2 * strlen(istream));
  int res = compress(ostream, &destLen, istream, destLen + 1);
  if(res == Z_BUF_ERROR){
    printf("Buffer was too small!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if(res ==  Z_MEM_ERROR){
    printf("Not enough memory for compression!\n");
    return 2;
  }
}
```

After careful reading of ["Utility Functions"](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Utility) from documentation. Full correct code:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "zlib.h"
int main()
{
  const char *istream = "some foo";
  ulong srcLen = strlen(istream)+1;      // +1 for the trailing `\0`
  ulong destLen = compressBound(srcLen); // this is how you should estimate size 
                                         // needed for the buffer
  char* ostream = malloc(destLen);
  int res = compress(ostream, &destLen, istream, srcLen); 
  // destLen is now the size of actuall buffer needed for compression
  // you don't want to uncompress whole buffer later, just the used part
  if(res == Z_BUF_ERROR){
    printf("Buffer was too small!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if(res ==  Z_MEM_ERROR){
    printf("Not enough memory for compression!\n");
    return 2;
  }

  const char *i2stream = ostream;
  char* o2stream = malloc(srcLen);
  ulong destLen2 = destLen; //destLen is the actual size of the compressed buffer
  int des = uncompress(o2stream, &srcLen, i2stream, destLen2);
  printf("%s\n", o2stream);
  return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
luk32:gcc -lz ./zlib.c 
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ./a.out 
some foo
```